# Which of the early game set piece shootouts can be avoided?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

In Red Dead Redemption II there are a number of set piece shootouts early on in the game. I know that some can be avoided. For example, if you choose not to Rescue Micha you can avoid the shootout in Strawberry.

Can any of the others be avoided in some way? Such as the Shootout against Cornwall in Valentine, or the confrontation with the Gray Family, and if so, how?